# Numbered list of non-contiguous items

Tags: formatting, numbering, lists, enumitem

I would like to generate a text that includes the following elements, in this order:

```
COMMENT 1: (some text)

(some more text, unrelated to COMMENT 1; this further piece of text may include lists, equations, section headers, subsection headers, etc.)

COMMENT 2: (some text)

(some more text as above, etc.).
```

In other words, I would like to have a list of items (COMMENT 1, COMMENT 2, etc.) that get automatically numbered and, at the same time, the items can be separated by chunks of text that do not belong to those items.

I am revising an article and it is useful to add those numbered comments in various parts of the text. It is useful to automatically give a number to those comments and a good way to do it, if possible, would be to generate a numbered list of non-contiguous items (and I will call these items "comments"). I am open to using any document class and package. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Two possibilities, from my point of view: defining an enumerated custom list with `enumitem`, and use its `resume` key, or define a new theorem-like structure (package `thmtools` can help customise the layout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{comment}
\newcommand\comment{\par\medskip
  \refstepcounter{comment}
  \noindent COMMENT \thecomment:\enspace\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\comment\label{firstcomment} (some text)

(some more text, unrelated to COMMENT \ref{firstcomment};
this further piece of text may include lists, equations,
section headers, subsection headers, etc.)

\comment (some text)

(some more text as above, etc.).

\end{document}
```

Of course, adapt the formatting to your exact needs.

If you want the text of the comment to be formatted specially, and/or you want some extra vertical spacing after the comment, you might be better off using `\newenvironment` instead of `\newcommand`.